# Is my understanding of how to calculate the reachability distance in local outlier factor correct?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, outliers

Reading lof implementation at : http://www.cse.ust.hk/~leichen/courses/msc-it5210/lectures/LOF_Example.pdf

the local reachability distance is given as :

[image]

I don't fully understand this equation as I think the max(distk(0) & dist(o,o`)) will never differ.

For example if I have a point "a" with knn distances (point label in brackets) of 2(b),3(c),4(d),5(e)

Take k=3 gives 3 nearest points for a :

"a" -> 2(b),3(c),4(d)

then the max of distk(a) & dist(a,a`) will be :

```
max(dist(d), dist(a,d)) = 

max(4,4) = 

4
```

In what scenario will the max distance values differ ?

Is my understanding of the reachability equation correct ?

Update : reading the wikipedia explanation for LOF : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_outlier_factor it states :

```
In words, the reachability distance of an object A from B is the true distance of the two objects, but at least the \mbox{k-distance} of B.
```

What is the k distance of B ? What is the point that distance B is being compared with ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The source your are using has the formula incorrect.**

Use the primary source of LOF; in particular if in doubt.

It uses the **k-distance of the neighbor** object, not of the candidate.

This distance is **asymmetric**, so make sure you are using the correct objects. One clearly does not want all distances to be the same - so try switching the arguments.

See also Wikipedia. If I'm not mistaken, the formula is correct there (otherwise, please fix it).

Comment: thanks, I think I'm a little clearer but still do not fully understand, please see question update ?

Comment: See the original LOF publication, it gives a precise definition of k-distance and kNN, where other papers are much sloppier.